# mysql connection with scala and sbt

Tags: mysql, scala, jdbc, intellij-idea, sbt

I have added my jar file in my `built.sbt`. But still I'm getting the following error. I've tried all the possible answers from the net, everything is about adding the jar file. But I'm getting the error even after adding the jar file in my build. Can anyone suggest a solution for this. I'm new to this topic

MY CODE

```
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.Connection


case class Emp(First_name: String)
{
  override def toString():String=
{
  "First Name: "+First_name
}
}

object MysqlScala {

def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {

// JDBC CONNECTION
val driver = "com.sql.jdbc.Driver"
val url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/employees"
val username = "employees"
val password = ""


//CONNECTION ESTABLISHMENT TO THE DATABASE

Class.forName(driver);
val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)

//CREATING THE STATEMENT FOR RUNNING THE QUERY

val statement = connection.createStatement()
val resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT first_name FROM employees;")

while (resultSet.next()) {
  val e = Emp(resultSet.getString("first_name"))
  println(e)
}

}

}
```

BUILD FILE

```
name := "MysqlScala"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.42"
```

This is the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at MysqlScala$.main(MysqlScala.scala:28)
at MysqlScala.main(MysqlScala.scala)

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `build.sbt` is perfect.

So `ClassNotFoundException` can be due to two reasons `1) jdbc jar file is not added to the project library` or `2) there are two jdbc libraries in the project and are conflicting`.

So you need to go

```
file --> Project Structure --> libraries
```

Check for both the cases mentioned above. If the `jar` is missing, you need to add it manually.

Comment: when I checked as you said there were two folders named class and source, both had the jar file. I tried deleting one file and the other separately but it did not work out. Can u suggest some other way? Should i add jar file in any other folder manually like in the jdk folder

Comment: did you delete them ? if yes then just package as usual and it should reappear

Comment: its not reappearing

Comment: then you will have to locate the mysql connector jar and add in the library.

Comment: There is a menu for invalidate cache and restart. Did you try that?

Comment: `File --> Invalidate Caches/Restart`